# Google cloud bucket does not update uploaded files

Tags: html, bucket, uploading

I have a basic Google cloud bucket site to test out a website. I can upload stuff just fine, but when I want to update a file, say index.html, the new file is uploaded but when I preview it using the copy url in a browser it displays the old version of the file.Is there some sort of cache that needs clearing down first?

Uploaded many updated files but the browser preview always shows the old version, even after I have deleted or renamed the old version. The only way I can get it to show a new version is to set up a new bucket, upload the new files and preview.

Answer (score 2):

try to access your url as  your-url-example.com?anyparam=anyvalue (the different param value will force the get the new version and not the cached one, usually I use timestamp as param value)

Comment: Thanks Franklin! I have it working now. Seems there is a considerable time delay for the servers to be refreshed!